# How to open a components' schematic symbol for editing quickly in Altium

Tags: altium

Let's say I have a component in my schematic in Altium. I can see the schematic library it came from and its Design Item ID. However to edit it, I need to open the schematic library and look for the schematic symbol manually.
In the "Components" panel I can click on any component and select "edit", however I still need to manually select the library it is in, find the component and then right click on it to access this menu.

Is there a faster way to jump to the schematic symbol in the library directly through a component that is in a schematic?

Comment: Please edit your question and add some very important details such as which schematic editing package you are using?  There are many available and the details of how they work are different.

Comment: Sorry added it as a label but forgot to add in title/content. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Double click the component, note the library name (you likely already have it open) , copy the Design item ID (Ctrl-C), switch to SCH LIB view for the library and paste (Ctrl-V) into the box at the top.

I don't know of a faster way.

Keep in mind that you should not be casually editing library components regularly as the edit may affect other PCBs if they are updated from that library. You may want to copy the existing component into a new Design item ID or a new library.

Comment: Yep make the tool for designers not using they're part vault subscription as clunky as possible...